# Finite-valued and measurable on a closed interval implies bounded

Tags: integration, probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

A problem in Billingsley's Probability and Measure says that if $f: [0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is finite-valued and Borel-measurable, then $f$ may be assumed integrable, and even bounded.

I don't see how this is true though. For example define $f$ as
$$f=0 \text{ on } [0,1/2)$$
$$f = 1 \text{ on } [1/2, 3/4)$$
$$f = 2 \text{ on } [3/4, 7/8)$$
$$ \vdots$$
$$ f = n \text{ on } \Big[\frac{2n-1}{2^n}, \frac{2n+1}{2^{n+1}}\Big)$$

Then $f(x) < \infty$ for all $x \in [0,1]$ and $f$ is measurable since it is a step function and takes only discrete values. However $f$ is not bounded on $[0,1]$.

What's wrong with this attempted counterexample? How would the statement be proven?

Comment: Which page and problem? Either Billingsley is wrong, or you are leaving out some context.

Comment: @MikeEarnest It's problem 17.10 (pg 230) in 3rd edition, or problem 17.8 (pg 227) in 2nd edition. exact statement is "Let $f$ be a finite-valued Borel function over $[0,1]$. 
(a) Show that f may be assumed integrable, or even bounded."

Comment: You left out this part from your quote, which is necessary to understand what Billingsly is talking about: "By
the following steps, prove Lusin’s theorem: For each $\epsilon$ there exists a
continuous function $g$ such that $\lambda[x \in  (0, 1): f(x ) \neq  g (x )] < \epsilon.$"

Comment: @MikeEarnest right, I understood that as the end goal but the statement I am trying to prove should be true on its own as a step in that proof, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I suspected, you left out context. The problem is about proving Lusin's theorem for functions on $[0,1]$. When part (a) says "Show that $f$ may be assumed to be integrable [or bounded]", what Billingsley means is that

> "Show that if Lusin's theorem is true for all integrable [or bounded] functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$, then it is true for all Borel functions $f:[0,1]\to \mathbb R$."

Comment: yes, that makes sense! A miscommunication I guess.

Comment: Is the point that any Borel function can be represented by an integrable or bounded functions? I also don't see how this can be true.

Comment: @900edges The idea is to _approximate_ $f$ by a bounded function. This is a separate question, so if you want help with that you should post it as a separate question (including all relevant context).